# PHP: Explode on 3rd character

Tags: php, explode

i have a problem, i am using `dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);` to get a the url of the current page and i have ended up with this `/clients/sherloc_media/install` and im trying to use `explode()` to get just this `/clients/sherloc_media` i need this for 1 variable and then i need `sherloc_media` for another, i have been attempting this for the past few hours as the `/clients/sherloc_media` i am going to be using as the `$root` variable,

Somehow i have ended up with links like this `http://localhost/clients/sherloc_media/operate/opertate/index.php`

when its suposed to be `http://localhost/clients/sherloc_media/opertate/index.php`

any help would be great thanks, i dont have any code that ive used to get the error result as i have been deleting and starting again, you know the crack, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of many ways:

```
$firstPart = substr(rtrim($path, '/'), 0, strrpos($path, '/'));
```

Or if you prefer explode:

```
$parts = explode('/', trim($path, '/'));
$firstPart = $parts[0] . '/' . $parts[1];
```